# How to encrypt Ubuntu home folder or partition and still able to hibernate/sleep my PC?

Tags: software-recommendation, dual-boot, encryption, bootloader, truecrypt

I am currently dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.  During installation of Ubuntu, I chose to encrypt my home folder.  I just don't like the fact that I can't put my computer to sleep or hibernate.  I decided I could try something else.

Now I don't have a lot of experience with bootloaders, but I was thinking of using [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to encrypt both partitions by encrypting Windows then installing Ubuntu on a pre-encrypted partition. I'm not sure that will work out too well.  What tools should I use to nicely encrypt and dual-boot both Windows 7, and Ubuntu while capable of hibernating or putting my computer to sleep? I would also prefer not to hurt my PC performance to much either.

Comment: I am not sure to help you here - but I work with truecrypt a lot and as far as I know the program it works different then file encryption. It works with an encrypted container. So this works different and windows has its own folder encryption techn. I am not sure if TC would be first choice here. There are better implemented tools for that. But be advised: If you lose your password - or sth. else bad happens your data will be lost.

Comment: @Peterling, thanks for your comment. Would you mind giving me some examples of "better implemented tools" and which you'd use for whatever reason? I would appreciate it.

Comment: @user68186 I just  skimmed your link and it looks like it just shows me how to make a .tc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the TC forums, you must decrypt the system, install both OS's so that dual-boot is working, then encrypt the system using the "dual boot" option in TC. See [here](http://forums.truecrypt.org/viewtopic.php?t=27064).

Comment: I have a working dual boot setup. But how do you know that TC "dual boot" option will encrypt both Windows, and Ubuntu?

Comment: Good question. That thread doesn't mention if Linux gets encrypted. Try this thread instead: http://forums.truecrypt.org/viewtopic.php?p=61064#61064